# I don't found why I can change my var:Bool on a struct

Tags: swift, swiftui

I created a swift file who define me a var :

```
import Foundation

struct Newspaper: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let url: String
    let image: String
    var favorite: Bool
    
    mutating func changeFavorite() {
        favorite.toggle()
    }
}

struct NewspaperRegion: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let region: String
    var newspapers: [Newspaper]
}

var  newspaperRegion: [NewspaperRegion] = [
    NewspaperRegion(region: "France",
                    newspapers: [Newspaper(name: "Les Echos", url: "lesechos.fr", image: "lesEchos", favorite: false),
                                 Newspaper(name: "Le Parisien", url: "leparisien.fr", image: "leParisien", favorite: true),
                                 Newspaper(name: "Le Figaro", url: "lefigaro.fr", image: "leFigaro", favorite: true),
                                 Newspaper(name: "L'Equipe", url: "lequipe.fr", image: "lEquipe", favorite: true),
                                 Newspaper(name: "Le Monde", url: "lemonde.fr", image: "leMonde", favorite: true),
                                 Newspaper(name: "Le Canard Enchainé", url: "lecanardenchaine.fr", image: "canardenchaine", favorite: true),
                                 Newspaper(name: "Libération", url: "liberation.fr", image: "liberation", favorite: true),
                                 Newspaper(name: "20Minutes", url: "20Minutes.fr", image: "20Minutes", favorite: true),
                                 Newspaper(name: "France Soir", url: "francesoir.fr", image: "francesoir", favorite: true),
                                 Newspaper(name: "l'Humanité", url: "humanite.fr", image: "lhumanite", favorite: true),
                                 Newspaper(name: "L'Obs", url: "nouvelobs.com", image: "lobs", favorite: true),
                                 Newspaper(name: "Le journal du Dimanche", url: "lejdd.fr", image: "lejdd", favorite: true),
                                 Newspaper(name: "L'Opinion", url: "lopinion.fr", image: "lopinion", favorite: true),
                                 Newspaper(name: "Mediapart", url: "mediapart.fr", image: "mediapart", favorite: true),
                                 Newspaper(name: "La Republique du Centre", url: "larep.fr", image: "larep", favorite: true)]),
    NewspaperRegion(region: "USA",
                    newspapers: [Newspaper(name: "New York Times", url: "nytimes.com", image: "nyTimes", favorite: true),
                                 Newspaper(name: "The Wall Street Journal", url:"wsj.com", image: "wallStreet", favorite: true),
                                 Newspaper(name: "The Washington Post", url: "washingtonpost.com", image: "washingtonPost", favorite: true)]),
    NewspaperRegion(region: "England",
                    newspapers: [Newspaper(name: "The Guardian", url: "theguardian.com", image: "theGuardian", favorite: true)]),
    NewspaperRegion(region: "Pakistan",
                    newspapers: [Newspaper(name: "Dawn", url: "dawn.com", image: "dawn", favorite: true)]),
    NewspaperRegion(region: "Australia",
                    newspapers: [Newspaper(name: "The Sydney Morning Herald", url: "smh.com.au", image: "sydneyMorning", favorite: true)]),
    NewspaperRegion(region:"China",
                    newspapers: [Newspaper(name: "China Daily", url: "chinadaily.com.cn", image: "chinaDaily", favorite: true)]),
    NewspaperRegion(region:"India",
                    newspapers: [Newspaper(name: "Times of India", url: "timesofindia.com", image: "timesIndia", favorite: true)])
]
```

Second, in a settings view, I want to give the possibility to change the "favorite" var :

```
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(newspaperRegion) { region in
                    Section(header: Text("\(region.region)")) {
                        ForEach(region.newspapers) { newspaper in
                            HStack {
                                Text(newspaper.name)
                                    .foregroundColor(newspaper.favorite == true ? Color.blue : Color.red)
                                Button(action: {
                                    newspaper.changeFavorite()
                                }) {
                                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Edit your list of newspaper", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

I have this error : "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'newspaper' is a 'let' constant"

I tried without mutating and toggle directly from Button, I tried to pass the var declaration on the view directly

Please note that I'm learning and I don't want just the answer, I would like to understand why.

I tried chatGPT but he gave me what I did ... XD

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) Globals are generally bad practice but with SwiftUI they don’t work, they aren’t capable of reloading views

Comment: @loremipsum has a good point here - SwiftUI is data driven. For your `View` to update the value, you would need something like `@State` - as [this article says](https://doordash.engineering/2022/05/31/how-the-swiftui-view-lifecycle-and-identity-work/), a SwiftUI view is a function of its state. It does not know that state has changed with a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

`newspaperRegion` should be a property in either your view as a @State var or a @Published var in your observable view model class.